# I need to retrieve digits before enter key and the space before it using regex

Tags: regex, uipath

I need to retrieve digits before enter key and the space before it using regex.

I have used the following expression to extract data from the pdf file.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\/\d{10} \d{2}.*

PH/2400310945 01.09.21 MYDOWNLOAD 19307.92-           0 **-19,307.92**
PV/5992278688 23.09.21 99140806 184832.4      144.40 **184,688.00**
PV/5992278699 23.09.21 99140807 13939.6       10.89 **13,928.71**
PV/5992285849 24.09.21 99140824 95845.48       74.88 **95,770.60**
PV/5992286716 24.09.21 99140822 73321.58       57.28 **73,264.30**
PV/5992286738 24.09.21 99140823 246443.22      192.53 **246,250.69**
```

Now I need to extract only the **last part** which is highlighted in BOLD,  My requirement is that I need to extract all digits from enter until the previous space which i failed to achieve using split string in uipath since the digits are dynamic in length.

Appreciate you inputs for the same.

This is how the data looks in IEnumerable

[image: This is how it looks in IEnumerable]

I have tried all the following

[image]

Regards,
Manjesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can match the numbers at the end of the string, including the leading space.

`-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aoue4p/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/s3b7fw)

For example

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @" -?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$").Value;
```

Comment: Hi, this works in regex however it did not work in Assign Activity of uipath. system.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(item.ToString," -?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$").Value

Comment: @manjeshkumar Can you try it like this? `(?m) -?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$` See https://ideone.com/XyTRtv

Comment: Hi, I have added some more information to the original post

Comment: @manjeshkumar Are there more spaces after the last digits? `(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?[\p{Zs}\t]*$`  What do you get  when you print a single `item.ToString()` ?

Comment: @manjeshkumar Did it work out?

Comment: Hi, This is the content of item.ToString PH/2400310945 01.09.21 WARRANTY2021091D 19307.92-           0 -19,307.92

Comment: @manjeshkumar Note that it is `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and not `system.Text.RegularExpressions` Also you can add an `@` sign before the pattern like `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @" -?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?$").Value;`  See https://ideone.com/s3b7fw

Comment: Hi , I am not successful I tried all that is there, it is return blank

Comment: @manjeshkumar Can you print the result of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]*\r?$").Value;` and print the result of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, @"(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]*").Value;`

Comment: @manjeshkumar Did you get any result?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delayed response. I am not able to add the @ symbol before the " it gives me an error. I ran the first expression and the output was **@" -19,307.92** and the result for the second expression is a space and **01.09**. I hope I could have shown the screen shot.

Comment: Hi, It worked with this expression. **System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(item.ToString,"(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]-?\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?(?m)[\p{Zs}\t]*\r?$").Value** Thank you so much for all that help